# Why does using assignment instead of append give me different results while the reference copies of sublist

Tags: python, python-3.x

The * is creating multiple reference copies of sublist. The changes made in any item will get changed to all the sublists.
Example:

```
a=[[]]*3
a[1].append(7)
print(a)
```

Output: [[7], [7], [7]]

But if we do a[1]=7 then output will be [[], 7, []]

How come?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a[1].append(7)` mutates the inner list, `a[1] = 7` mutates the outer list. Assigning something else to a reference *doesn't change the thing that was being referenced originally*.

The following analogous example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> a.append(42)
>>> print(a, b)
[42] [42]
```

Versus:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = a
>>> a = 42
>>> print(a, b)
42 []
```

Comment: Thanks analogous example makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [[]] * 3
```

This creates two new lists. One list is called `a` and the other list is contained 3 times in `a`.

`a[1]` refers to the other list (just as `a[0]` and `a[2]` would refer to the same other list).

If you use `a[1].append`, you modify the other list. So if you print `a`, you will see the modified other list 3 times.

```
a[1] = 7
```

This does not modify the other list. Instead, it replaces the value at index 1 in list `a` (which used to be the other list before) by the value 7.

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

`a=[[]]*3`

you are creating a list that contains the same `[]` object 3 times.
So when you append to `[]`, all of its copies get appended to as well, giving us `a = [[7], [7], [7]]`.

It is easier to see if instead you do `b = []` and then `a = [b]*3`.
Then if you append to b, you expect it to happen to all 3 slots.

---

However when using `a[1] = 7` you **overwrite** the object in position 1 of a. Instead of a list, that object is now an int.

---

I suggest you research [python mutable objects](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) because lists, dicts and sets are all mutable objects and knowing their properties may help you understand their behavior.